# how to read Keycloak user last logged in events

Tags: keycloak

I want to be able to read user last logged in event(Keycloak). So I have read through the keycloak docs and could not find any admin api that accomplishes this. what I did so far was to add a SPI section on the standalone-ha-xml file and enable the Login event on keycloak interface. I know that these logs are store in a file called audit.log and in a JSON format. So I am not sure if it will be a good idea to try to read this file and find out when was the last time a user has logged in. any ideas?

```
<audit-logging>
  <file-audit-log name="local-audit" path="audit.log" relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" format="JSON"/>
</audit-logging>

<spi name="eventsListener">
     <default-provider>jboss-logging</default-provider>
       <provider name="jboss-logging" enabled="true">
         <properties>
           <property name="success-level" value="info"/>
           <property name="error-level" value="warn"/>
        </properties>
       </provider>
</spi>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think there is a better way to do this. At first you need to open `Events` menu and then select `Config` tab. Check `Save Events` option in `Login Events Settings` group. You can specify types (`LOGIN`) and expiration too (for how long it will be stored).
Then you can read them using admin API `GET /{realm}/events` [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_realms_admin_resource) (authorization required)

`https://{host}:{port}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/events?type=LOGIN`

Or you can query for them in Keycloak database but I think first option is better:

```sql
SELECT id, client_id, details_json, error, ip_address, realm_id, session_id, event_time, type, user_id 
FROM event_entity WHERE type = 'LOGIN';
```

Comment: thanks I managed to get login event and I also attached the user query to the url passing the user id just to filter for a specific user.